# How insert a canvas using a Mesh inside a WebGL Render in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm experiencing with Three JS after reading an article about augmented reality using a webcam.
Like experiment, i try to put a simple canvas in a scene, where before i have put a webglrender, by insert an webcam stream.
I read in this article (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/10/an-ar-game-technical-overview/) that for the virtual scene, is needed create a virtual scene, where is renderer by the object webglrenderer, and a reality scene(the webcam). In my file testingthreejs.js, between the line 30 and 41 is where i wrote the lines for create the new scene (the virtual), and where i created and inserting the canvas inside my mesh object.
But nothing happen, ¿how i can insert the canvas like a Mesh object?
I try to avoid draw a canvas, as it is supposed that the rendering by canvas is more slow that rendering with webgl (i also think use the ray class)
This is my gist : https://gist.github.com/fernandosg/75ec701c0295761a77e6, inside are the files testingthreejs.js and index.html.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Stemkoski s website](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/#texture-from-canvas) which has a lot of examples with very nice explanations. 
I think [this](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html) is what you are looking for, take a look at the script.

More precisely, here is the commented code :

```
/////// draw text on canvas /////////

// create a canvas element
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
context1.font = "Bold 40px Arial";
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.95)";
context1.fillText('Hello, world!', 0, 50);

// canvas contents will be used for a texture
var texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1) 
texture1.needsUpdate = true;

var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture1, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
material1.transparent = true;

var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas1.width, canvas1.height),
    material1
  );
mesh1.position.set(0,50,0);
scene.add( mesh1 );

/////// draw image on canvas /////////

// create a canvas element
var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
// canvas contents will be used for a texture
var texture2 = new THREE.Texture(canvas2);

// load an image
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "images/Dice-Blue-1.png";
// after the image is loaded, this function executes
imageObj.onload = function()
{  
    context2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    if ( texture2 ) // checks if texture exists
        texture2.needsUpdate = true;
};  

var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture2, side:THREE.DoubleSide} );
material2.transparent = true;

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas2.width, canvas2.height),
    material2
  );
mesh2.position.set(0,50,-50);
scene.add( mesh2 ); 
}
```

Comment: Hi P.Ellul, the example not working for what i looking for, the modification that i was make with the example was : delete the new scene and camera, and  put the new mesh inside the scene with the position 0,50,-50 (even put 0,0 not work ). The changes that i make are in this new gist https://gist.github.com/fernandosg/14a3b915e34b0d442b60
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe i am getting closer to the solution, finally i can put the canvas (using a MeshBasicMaterial and a PlaneGeometry), but now the canvas was drawed, the video was not rendered:
[problem canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLIPn.png)

The code:

```
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width=512;
canvas.height=512;  
var video=document.createElement("video");
streamVideo(video);
var canvasContext=canvas.getContext("2d");
var glCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var renderer_webgl=new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:glCanvas});
renderer_webgl.setSize(512,512);
renderer_webgl.autoClear=false;
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(glCanvas);
var camera = new THREE.Camera();
var scene=new THREE.Scene();
var geometry=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2,0);
var texture=new THREE.Texture(canvas);
var material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map:texture,
            depthTest:false,
            depthWrite:false
        });
var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);

canvas_draw=document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas_draw.width=128;
        canvas_draw.height=128;
        ctx=canvas_draw.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#AAA";
        ctx.fillRect(1,1,20,25);
// HERE IS WHEN INSERT THE CANVAS
var texture_canvas=new THREE.Texture(canvas_draw);
texture_canvas.needsUpdate=true;
var basic_material_canvas=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map:texture_canvas
});
var mesh_canvas=new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2,0),basic_material_canvas);
scene.add(mesh);
scene.add(mesh_canvas);
function renderScenes(){
    renderer_webgl.render(scene,camera);
}

function loop(){
    if(video.readyState===video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA){
        canvas.changed=true;
        canvasContext.drawImage(video,0,0);
        verifyDetector();
        texture.needsUpdate=true;
        texture_canvas.needsUpdate=true;
        renderScenes();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

function verifyDetector(){
    detector = new AR.Detector();
    imageData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var markers = detector.detect(imageData);
    /*if(markers.length>0)
        canvasContext.drawImage(canvas_draw,markers[0].corners[0].x,markers[0].corners[0].y);               
        */
}
```

¿Why this happen?